# Charts in Oracle APEX display group as label

Tags: oracle-apex

As mentioned in the Title im creating a Webapplication with Oracle APEX and my Charts are showing Group (im German so on my charts it shows "Gruppe") instead of the selected Labels.
First few labels are correct but the it'll take Group 6 for example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing x-axis labels like *Gruppe x*?

**The Reason?**
When the number of data points for a series is higher than the number of x-axis labels being rendered.

**What to do?**
Please run the SQL query in SQL Workshop,  and identify any duplicate entries for a given x-axis label. Probably, you will need to update the SQL query, to avoid returning duplicate data.

Comment: Hi Mónica, what if I have a dynamic number of data point per x-axis, for i.e., for Jan I have 3 distinct series but for Feb I have 5. Ideally I'd wish to have a query with:
1. label (date and time)
2. serie_name (let's say job_title)
3. value (let's say count of new hires of that job title in that given date)

If, for i.e., in Feb I had way more new hires than in Jan, I will end up with way more data point in such x-axis, which will also make these funny "Group 1", "Group 2" and etc.

The workaround I am doing right now is creating manually multiple series one for each job_title...

Comment: Hi Rafael - Good point!